# How to prove four variable inequality involving sums of cube roots

Tags: inequality

Suppose that $a,b,c,d>0$. Is there a proof that $$ a\sqrt[3]{\frac{1+d}{b^3+abcd}}+b\sqrt[3]{\frac{1+d}{c^3+abcd}}+c\sqrt[3]{\frac{1+d}{a^3+abcd}}\geq 3?$$
I tried for example Jensen, Karamata, Power mean and Minkowski's inequality without success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inequality can be written as
$$(1+d)\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{a}{\sqrt[3]{b^3+abcd}}\right)^3\geq27$$
By the generalized Hölder's inequality
$$\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{a}{\sqrt[3]{b(b^2+d\,ca)}}\right)^3\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}}ab\right)\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}}a(b^2+d\,ca)\right)\geq\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}}a\right)^5$$
This reduces the problem to
$$(1+d)\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}}a\right)^5\geq27\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}}ab\right)\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}}a(b^2+d\,ca)\right)$$
But
$$\sum_{\text{cyc}}a(b^2+d\,ca)=\sum_{\text{cyc}}ab^2+d\sum_{\text{cyc}}ca^2=(1+d)\sum_{\text{cyc}}ab^2$$
So it's just
$$\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}}a\right)^5\geq27\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}}ab\right)\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}}ab^2\right)$$

And see [Inequality problem $(a+b+c)^5\geq27(ab+bc+ca)(ab^2+bc^2+ca^2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/709654/inequality-problem-abc5-geq27abbccaab2bc2ca2/#710324).

Comment: Nice +1.  BTW Holder directly gives $$\left(\sum a\sqrt[3]{\frac{1+d}{b^3+a b c d}}\right)^3(\sum \text{ab})\left(\sum a\left(b^2+a c d\right)\right)\geq  (1+d)(\sum a)^5$$

Comment: @Macavity Nice shortcut! I'll edit it.

Comment: Where did you get that first inequality? Is there some magic in the cyc-notation as I don't see where the term $\frac{b}{\sqrt[3]{c^3+abcd}}$ is?

Comment: @Student: Yes, there is, $\sum\limits_\text{cyc}E(a,b,c)$ means a cyclic sum so it's $E(a,b,c)+E(b,c,a)+E(c,a,b)$. (d is treated as a constant there)