# Inequality problem $(a+b+c)^5\geq27(ab+bc+ca)(ab^2+bc^2+ca^2)$

Tags: inequality

While solving one inequality, I arrived at a much simpler, but still nontrivial inequality
$$(a+b+c)^5\geq27(ab+bc+ca)(ab^2+bc^2+ca^2)$$
where $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers.

It apparently holds, but I can't seem to find a proof.
The problem is it's not symmetric and applying inequalities $(a+b+c)^2\geq3(ab+bc+ca)$ or $a^3+b^3+c^3\geq ab^2+bc^2+ca^2$ won't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share you initial ineqaulity? Any additional infomration may help other users.

Comment: Are you sure your inequality is true? This comment is *not* a solution, but just a few rmks that might not lead to a solution but might rule out some approaches. 

We see $(ab+bc+ca)(ab^2 + bc^2 + ca^2) = abc(ab + bc + ca)(b/c + c/a + a/b).$ The function $x \mapsto x^{-1}$ is convex on $(0,\infty)$ and so Jensen implies $(a+b+c)^2 \leq (ab+bc+ca)(b/c+c/a+a/b).$ On the other hand, AM-GM tells us that $abc \leq (a+b+c)^3/27.$ Both these inequalities seem to be sharp. So either the inequality you posed is *very* sharp and a simple approach like this isn't going to work or the ineq. isn't ok.

Comment: Here's an idea. (I don't know if it helps.) Let $f(a,b,c)=(a+b+c)^5-27(ab+bc+ca)(ab^2+bc^2+ca^2)$. You need to show that the minimum value of $f$ for $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}^+$ is nonnegative. Suppose the minimum occurs at $(a_0,b_0,c_0)$. Note that $f$ is homogeneous: $f(ka,kb,kc)=f(a,b,c)$, so WLOG assume $a_0=1$ and minimize $f(b,c)=(1+b+c)^5-27(b+bc+c)(b^2+bc^2+c)$.

Comment: @Stefan4024: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707212/how-to-prove-four-variable-inequality-involving-sums-of-cube-roots

Comment: @Raghav: But you are right, it seems to be rather tight. I can't quite see the Jensen, but it's a simple Cauchy $(ab+bc+ca)(\frac ab+\frac bc+\frac ca)\ge(a+b+c)^2$. So you are right it's a product of 2 competing inequalities, but it's still one way in the end, I have verified that with Mathematica both formally and numerically.

Comment: I don't have a solution, but we have the inequality $(a+b+c)^3 \geq \frac{27}{4} (ab^2 + bc^2 + ca^2 + abc)$, while you wish to prove that $(a+b+c)^3 \geq 9 (ab^2 + bc^2 + ca^2)$. Perhaps the two are related?

Comment: @user92774 Your last inequality is not true, consider $a=b=1,c=0$.

Comment: @user2345215 true, but if you let $a+b+c = 1$ and $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}^+$ the maximum is reached at $\frac{1}{9}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without loss of generality, let $a+b+c=3$. Then we only have to prove
$$(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)(ab+bc+ac)\le 9$$
Assume $b=\text{mid}(a,b,c)$, then we have
$$c(b-a)(b-c)\le 0\Longleftrightarrow a^2b+b^2c+c^2a\le b(a^2+ac+c^2)$$
So
$$(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)(ab+bc+ac)\le b(a^2+ac+c^2)(ab+bc+ac)$$
Using AM-GM inequality, we get
$\begin{align*}
b(a^2+ac+b^2)(ab+bc+ca)&\le\,b\cdot\dfrac{(a^2+ac+c^2+ab+bc+ac)^2}{4}=
b\cdot\dfrac{(a+c)^2(a+b+c)^2}{4}\\
&=\dfrac{9}{8}\cdot 2b\cdot(a+c)\cdot(a+c)\\
&\le\dfrac{9}{8}\cdot\dfrac{(2b+a+c+a+c)^3}{27}\\
&=\,9
\end{align*}$
Done!

Comment: Very nice! There's just a small typo in the last inequality, it should be a 3rd power, but otherwise it's perfect!